# Can I configure parameters when launching flatpak apps from the GUI?

Tags: executable, parameter, flatpak

One of my Flatpak application stopped working properly, probably after a silent upgrade. I found a fix online that tells me to add a parameter. That fix works. Nonetheless, I like running that app from the GUI as it's much less time consuming than typing its full name in the console.

For a concrete example, my program is VSCodium, installed with Flatpak. The fix is to run it with GPU disabled.

Currently, the GUI runs the command `flatpak run com.vscodium.codium` with probably a few more parameters, I would like it to run `flatpak run com.vscodium.codium --disable-gpu`, keeping those extra parameters.

If it were an app installed through the native package manager, I'd modify the `.desktop` shortcut, but I can't find the ones created by flatpak, if any.

How do I achieve that? (Where are the `.desktop` files or is there a better way?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar [problem and researched](https://medium.com/@syafiqza/blank-screen-in-visual-studio-code-d84707001c94) the cause of it and it seems there's a cache connected with the GPU that has been corrupted.

I solved it by simply moving the GPUCache folder connected to Code/Codium.
On my system (Kubuntu) it's located here and installed Codium with flatpak.

```
cd ~/.var/app/com.vscodium.codium/config/VSCodium
```

Make sure that Code/codium is not running.
I just moved/renamed the GPUCache folder with

```
mv GPUCache/ GPUCache_old
```

For me that make Code/Codium start from the GUI-runner.

Edit; to answer your actual question as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089446/want-to-make-vscode-always-start-with-disable-gpu-option-from-everywhere-e), on my system the .desktop file is located at

```
cd /var/lib/flatpak/app/com.vscodium.codium/current/active/export/share/applications
```

Open `com.vscodium.codium.desktop` with nano and your parameter to the line with `Exec=`.

However this second solution did not solve it for me.

Hope that helps!